# How to show tomcat logging in a jsp page text area(realtime)?

Tags: html, jsp, tomcat, servlets, log4j

I have one jsp file which contains a form. Submitting the form calls a servlet which processes data sent. I want that when i click submit button, a text area is spanned and that should show my application's log in realtime.
I am using Tomcat 7.

Any sources will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One application I know that can do it is [Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/). It's basically just a WAR file that you deploy to your Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

PSI Probe is a community-driven fork of Lambda Probe distributed under the same open-source license (GPLv2).

https://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/